# Jupyter notebook shutting down while running the program

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, jupyter-notebook, interactive

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z2xxV.png)

I'm a beginner in the python programming. I have a large hdf5 file and was trying to implement interactive plotting using the following code. I need to zoom in, zoom out and also needs to know the x and y values at different points of the graph.

But whenever I try running the program, the output is shown for 2-3 seconds after which it displays the message "Jupyter notebook is not responding and needs to close the tab". What should I do in order to solve this problem? Should I modify my code or are there any alternatives?

The screenshot of the message is attached.

```
import  pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px
import numpy as np

file = "hdf5_file"
hf = pd.read_hdf(file,mode = 'r')

X = hf['Timestamp'].to_numpy()
difference = (X[0:] - X[0]) * (10 ** -9)

fig = px.line(hf, y=hf.Torque, x=difference)
fig.show()
```

Comment: Why not using matplotlib. It has ability of zooming in/out when diagram created.

Comment: I tried using "%matplotlib notebook." I was able to get the values. But I need a line plot where I can get the values of x and y while the mouse pointer scrolls over the plot (similar to the interactive feature in MATLAB)